# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, admob

I just import code source eclipse to android studio.

How can I fix it?

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.[enter image description here][1]motivation.cheer"
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 15
        multiDexEnabled false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    }
}
```

Comment: `applicationId "com.[enter image description here][1]motivation.cheer"` smells fishy. Is that what you really got in your build.gradle? Also, can you post the full stack trace of the build process so that we can have a look at what could be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Read this post on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  I encourage you to edit your question to increase the chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go to Build - Rebuild project.